# VB Script- read excel column values and assign it a dynamic array and form different sets of combinations of data

Tags: excel, vbscript, dynamic-arrays

I have a requirement to form a permutation data from the given set of values in excel sheet. Below are the details.

Let us say there are 5 columns and each column has some rows of data as below in input excel sheet.

```
   Column 1 - 2 values(ind,us)
   column 2 -1 value (a1)
   Column 3= 3 value(cat,dog,cow)
   column 4= 4 value(1,2,3,4)
   Column 5= 1 value(d)

The output excel has to be on below format.

   ind,a1,cat,1,d
   ind,a1,cat,2,d
   ind,a1,cat,3,d
   ind,a1,cat,4,d
   ind,a1,dog,1,d
   ind,a1,dog,2,d
   ind,a1,dog,3,d
   ind,a1,dog,4,d
   ind,a1,cow,1,d
   ind,a1,cow,2,d
   ind,a1,cow,3,d
   ind,a1,cow,4,d
   us,a1,cat,1,d
   us,a1,cat,2,d
   us,a1,cat,3,d
   us,a1,cat,4,d
   us,a1,dog,1,d
   us,a1,dog,2,d
   us,a1,dog,3,d
   us,a1,dog,4,d
   us,a1,cow,1,d
   us,a1,cow,2,d
   us,a1,cow,3,d
   us,a1,cow,4,d
```

please note the rows and column count are not constant.

Request all to give some thoughts to implement.
 Thanks,
 Rakesh

Comment: you should put your thoughts as well?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6764744/603855) for ways to get (all) combinations of elements with specified values for each slot. Just feed your data as an array of arrays to the Permute function or the .init method.